# Can TOR hide All of my Traffic

Tags: networking, tor

I suppose a bit of background is necessary. I am looking at how to host a website on the tor network and came across an interesting article explaining how it all works. 
[How To Host A Site on the Dark Web](https://medium.com/@jasonrigden/how-to-host-a-site-on-the-dark-web-38edf00996bf)

In this tutorial they say to install Ubuntu 16.04 Server which I assume is a full fledged operating system allowing applications like chrome and firefox. Currently my only linux exposure is my home laptop running Fedora.

My question about this tutorial is if I install tor the way they suggest, does the force all outbound traffic through the tor network?

```
sudo apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
```

I would like to get a raspberry pi 3 and put ubuntu server on it, then run all the traffic through the tor network. However everywhere I look it seems I have to run the tor browser or set up  a service like Tortilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only traffic going through the Tor network would be the website you are serving.  All other traffic would not be running through the Tor network.

Comment: I suppose that is why distros like TAILS exist. They have a limited set of applications which are all configured to run through TOR